# Is it possible to use a bash completion function to replace the current commandline arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

I am wondering if it is possible to replace all commandline arguments using a bash completion function.
Say for example that I have at the prompt:

```sh
command arg1 arg2 arg3<tab>
```

Say I press `<tab>` after I type `arg3`, and that my bash completion function only provides something like `final_result` as the only valid completion; is it possible to end up with

```sh
command final_result
```

after the completion function terminates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; the completion function only supplies new text which `bash` adds to the current command line; it cannot edit the current command line itself.

Comment: That is, adds to the current command line after removing the completed word. (I would have said something like "new text which `bash` uses to replace the completed word".) You can replace the word with arbitrary text; it doesn't need to be a suffix.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll mark it as resolved, until someone else pops up with a different answer